# Differential Equation with biology!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-fractions, biology

I am working on a growth model for bacteria as a function of a nutrient, and I am stuck. So the differential equation I am supposed to be solving is

$\frac{dN}{dT} = k(C_0 -\alpha N(T)) N$

The problem is here, is that I am supposed to be using partial fractions, and I am unfamiliar with them, except for about one lecture a long time ago. Can someone help me at least get started on where I need to go for partial fractions?

Comment: Are $N$ and $N(t)$ different? I'm assuming that $k, C_0$ and $\alpha$ are constants, but are there conditions on these constants?

Comment: My understanding is $N$ is the number of bacteria, and that $N(T)$ is the number of bacteria/volume

Comment: Okay. But nothing like $k, C_0,\alpha>0$? And could $N(T)$ be the number of bacteria at time $T$? I would expect the number of bacteria/volume would be $D(V)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We rewrite your equation as

$$\color{blue}{k} = \frac{1}{N(C_0 - \alpha N)} \frac{dN}{dt} = \color{blue}{\frac{1}{C_0}\left( \frac{1}{N} + \frac{\alpha}{C_0 - \alpha N} \right)\frac{dN}{dt}}$$

Now integrate both sides,

$$\int \color{blue}{k} \ dt = \int \color{blue}{\frac{1}{C_0}\left( \frac{1}{N} + \frac{\alpha}{C_0 - \alpha N} \right)\frac{dN}{dt}} dt = \frac{1}{C_0} \int \left( \frac{1}{N} + \frac{\alpha}{C_0 - \alpha N}  \right) dN$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes Thank you very much!

Comment: What happened to $\alpha$?

Comment: Amazing no one spotted that in six weeks. If it had been within a day or so, I would edit the post.

Comment: Why not edit now?

Comment: @Did Fair enough. Done